# cimg multiple window placement

Tags: c++, cimg

I'm using CImgDisplay to show a couple of images onscreen. My problem is that they're opening on top of the Command Prompt window and each other. Is there a way to make them open at a different location? I've looked through the CImg documentation and can't find anything.

Comment: I think it's not related to Cimg, you should show your window in an X,Y location and your windows should render your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CImgDisplay::move()` will probably help you, as it can move a window to a specific position.
If necessary, you can create an initially hidden windows, move it, then show it afterwards, using `CImgDisplay::show()`.